# Remote debugging WinForms application

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, remote-debugging

I would remote debugging application WinForm.

Steps I made
On the remote machine:

1. I installed "Remote Tools for Visual Studio 2017" and configured it for unauthorized access. [settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XdRro.png)
2. I launched the application that I want debug

On the local machine:

1. In the project, I selected "use a remote machine" and "enable native code debugging"
2. I chose Debugging -> Join the project, I changed the connection type to remote (without authorization), I clicked the search The remote computer has been found correctly. I found the process on the list and clicked attach After some time the error shows me: [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sxAmj.png)

What did I do wrong or what should I do to make it work?

Regards,
Tomasz

Comment: Please edit & add the error text (in English) to your question.

Comment: This is a pretty well-written question Tomasz.  Can you translate that error as @AlexK.asked in an [edit] to the question?  I think if you did, you may find some assistance faster.

Comment: Is there the same error if you disable 'enable native code debugging'?

Comment: Basically the error is described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/a-dcom-error-occurred-trying-to-contact-the-remote-computer-access-is-denied?view=vs-2019) with possible solutions

Comment: @AlexK.  I inserted the correct screenshot

Comment: @KubaMichałek Yes, I tried two case: with and without 'enable native code debugging'.  Also I tried solutions from topic from link - still have error

Comment: I used the advice from the article again and it worked. Thanks.